# Скачать элементы css Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите где скачать полный набор элементов Bootstrap, чтобы работал локально без интернета? Верстку делаю внутри компании, интернет часто отваливается и часть функционала (визуальная часть) не отображается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Comment: @Bookin Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С сайта бутстрапа.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Вообще, лучше все компоненты использовать локально.

Answer (score 0):

[там все пишет](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

если хочешь просто иконки можно подключить[fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/)